# SFTP Integration - SftpInboundFileSynchronizer - How not to download same file again

Tags: java, spring-integration

In my current application, using spring-batch job, I trigger the process to SFTP remote files to local directory, process it and delete files post processing.

```java
    @Bean("ftpMessageSource")
    @EndpointId("streamInboundAdapter")
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"), autoStartup = "false")
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(),""));
        source.setMaxFetchSize(10);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean(name="fileStore")
    public PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore() {
        PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
        metadataStore.setBaseDirectory("filestore");
        metadataStore.setFileName("filestore.properties");
        metadataStore.afterPropertiesSet();
        return metadataStore;
    }
```

As every file is processed, I make an entry of filename to fileStore.properties file.

```java
    
metadataStore.put(file.getName(),file.getName());
```

One issue, I ran into next time processing (w/o restarting server and kicking off the same process again) is - process gets same set of files again for processing.

I do not want to SFTP processed files, can you please point out which configuration I am missing to avoid downloading same files again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and delete files post processing.

So, file does not exist in local directory any more. Since you don't filter remote files, they are downloaded again as a new local copy.

The `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` logic is based on the `file.lastModified()` and if it is different from an existing entry, it is replaced and therefore pushed downstream.

Consider using an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` on the `sftpInboundFileSynchronizer`. This way the same file (if the same `lastModified`) is not going to be pulled from SFTP.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound